# Nested $lookup in array in object array - Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking to perform a $lookup on a nested array within an array, ideally with a pipeline for projection.

Here is a mock of my data source:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "title": "My first poll",
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "abc",
        "title": "First option",
        "voters": [ObjectId(), ObjectId()]
      },
      {
        "id": "def",
        "title": "second option",
        "voters": [ObjectId()]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

An array of `options` with an an array of `voters` as `ObjectId`'s - which references another collection as their `_id`. I've used `$lookup` previously but can't figure it out when nested this deep.

The result I need is, essentially swapping out the `ObjectId` for an object of some projected data.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "title": "My first poll",
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "abc",
        "title": "First option",
        "voters": [
          {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "name": "John Doe"
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "name": "Jane Doe"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "def",
        "title": "second option",
        "voters": [
          {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "name": "Bob Doe"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Other articles suggest bringing back the `voters` information as a new `addField` at root level and then using `$map` to pick out by `_id` - I just can't seem to crack it. Ended up doing it as a separate `.find()` and `.map()` in JS.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: COLLECTIONS.USERS,
    localField: 'options.voters',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'voterInfo'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.  Comments are in the pipeline.

```js
db.polls.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "options.voters",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "users",
      "pipeline": [
        { // $project what you need from users here
          "$project": {
            "name": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      // rebuild options
      "options": {
        // rewrite each option element
        "$map": {
          "input": "$options",
          "as": "option",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              // keep everything in option element
              "$$option",
              // rewrite voters
              {
                "voters": {
                  // get new content from users
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$users",
                    "as": "user",
                    "cond": {"$in": ["$$user._id", "$$option.voters"]}
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // don't need users anymore
    "$unset": "users"
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eY3R97tCTke).